# Make IFrame bigger

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am an absolute HTML and javascript beginner and I'm pretty sure, that is really easy to achieve.
I have the following generated IFRAME:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<iframe id = \"widget\" width=\"600\" height=\"140\" src=\"http://www.wetter.at/wetter/oesterreich/niederoesterreich/wiener-neudorf/widget/w600/color-standard?utm_source=widget&utm_medium="+top.location.hostname+"&utm_content="+top.location.href+"&utm_campaign=Wetter%2BWidget\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>");</script><center style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; font-size:11px; line-height:15px; font-family:arial;"><a href="http://www.wetter.at/wetter/oesterreich/niederoesterreich/wiener-neudorf" style="color:#4787a9; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Das aktuelle Wetter in Wiener Neudorf</a><br/><a href="http://www.wetter.at" style="color:#4787a9; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Alles zum Wetter in Österreich</a></center><br />
```

I'd like to have it in the middle of the screen and much bigger. The quality does not count, it is just for a presentation to show, how this could look like. 
Maybe you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<center><iframe width="90%" height="500px"></iframe></center>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried editing the width/height

```
width=\"600\" height=\"140\"
```

It's best to give it a class and edit it in the stylesheet

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<iframe id=\"widget\" width=\"600\" height=\"140\" class=\"iframe\" blah blah/></script>

.iframe{width:600px; height:140px; margin:auto;}
```

Please post your result after this

--EDIT--
In your `.html` file, in the `<head>` tag, make a `<style> </style>` tag.
Next edit your `Iframe` and include a `class="iframe"`.

Next add the following lines in `<style>`.

```
.html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

This sets the width and height of the page to 100%.
Now add this underneath the `.body{}` attribute

```
.iframe{
width:80%;
height:600px;
margin:100px auto 0 auto;
}
```

You can play around with these attributes. Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP might also want to make sure to remove those spaces around the `=` after `id` and you might want to escape your `"` for the class attribute

Comment: Sorry, only started with StackOverflow today

Comment: no worries. I'm being quite strict, but a lot of people copy+paste from here, and are quite likely to run into problems. Welcome aboard!

Comment: I already tried to edit the with and height. This does not change anything. :/

Comment: Have you tried adding it to a class and removing the standard width and height from the Iframe? If yes then try Kasynych's answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that... When I try to do it like Sickfire, it displays '.iframe{width:600px; height:140px; margin:auto;}' only...

Comment: I made a small edit, hope this makes everything clear.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I can actually move it around now. But which values do I have to change to make it bigger?

Comment: Just the width and the height.

Comment: Still does not change at all :(

Comment: To edit the size all you should do it change the width and height in the .iframe class, NOT the body and html classes, you can leave those two alone.

Comment: Yes, but if I change those, nothing happens. When I change the margin, the picture moves up or down, but it does not change its size.